# DAX - Join two disconnected table with measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

In PowerBI, I have an Opportunity Table and an Event Table that are not connected with a relationship.

**Opportunity Table**

| Opportunity_ID | Opportunity_Name | Opportunity_Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Opportunity1 | Opened |
| 2 | Opportunity2 | Closed |
| 3 | Opportunity3 | Opened |
| 4 | Opportunity4 | Opened |

**Event Table**

| Event_ID | Opportunity_ID | Event_Name | Event_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | Event1 | 1/1/2022 |
| 2 | 2 | Event2 | 1/2/2022 |
| 3 | 1 | Event3 | 1/3/2022 |
| 4 | 3 | Event4 | 1/4/2022 |

I want to create a table visual on powerBI then put Opportunity and Event on the columns and it shows the related event and opportunity (like with relationship)

The expected result is:

| Opportunity_Name | Opportunity_Status | Event_Name | Event_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Opportunity1 | Opened | Event3 | 1/3/2022 |
| Opportunity2 | Closed | Event1 | 1/1/2022 |
| Opportunity2 | Closed | Event2 | 1/2/2022 |
| Opportunity3 | Opened | Event4 | 1/4/2022 |
| Opportunity4 | Opened |  |  |

I want also to have the expected below result when I begin by puting Event on the table visual:(The other direction of the filter)

| Event_Name | Event_Date | Opportunity_Name | Opportunity_Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event1 | 1/1/2022 | Opportunity2 | Closed |
| Event2 | 1/2/2022 | Opportunity2 | Closed |
| Event3 | 1/3/2022 | Opportunity1 | Opened |
| Event4 | 1/4/2022 | Opportunity3 | Opened |

Is it possible to create a Measure (or two measures) that I can add to the table visual to do this kind of cross join ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `Merge Queries` in Power Query.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. But I forgot to mention that I am connecting with live connection to an as tabular model. So I can't use power query.

Comment: Then you can do with LOOKUPVALUE in DAX

Comment: On Live connection, you can not add columns or table, it can only create a report level measure.